# Angular library of standalone components

Tags: angular, angular-library, ng-build, angular-standalone-components

I've been trying to create an Angular library of standalone components. I've generated a `.tgz` file using `npm pack` of the library, and I'm trying to use/import some of it's components into another Angular application.

But when I do that, using the `imports` array, I'm seeing a build error:

> error NG1010: 'imports' must be an array of components, directives, pipes, or NgModules,
> Value is of type '[CommonModule, (not statically analyzable)]'

The *"not statically analyzable"* is coming in place of the componenet that I'm trying to import from the created library.

The library works just fine without any issues, the issue shows up when I try to use it in another application by installing the `.tgz` file.

I've not yet been able to find an issue similar to mine—hence asking this question.

Comment: The problem was there were a couple of components which weren't available/defined at the time they were being imported, so used forwardRef for those components to get rid of the issues.